# How to deploy a Monorepo Using Yarn Workspaces to Vercel

Tags: vercel, monorepo

Need ways to deploy a Monorepo Using Yarn Workspaces to Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

There's very well put out info ion this at following links:

- https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/
- https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-yarn-monorepos-to-vercel